# Send an email when an incorrect password is entered

Tags: fedora, pam

On the Debian workstations at work that I administrate I get an email whenever somebody tries to call `sudo` with the exact command that they have tried, the machine and their username. This is really helpful as I can then incorporate their `sudo apt install …` command with the configuration management, install the package that they need and send them an email.

For my personal laptop I would like to have a similar thing. I would like to get a system email when an incorrect password has been entered anywhere (login screen, screen locker, …) such that I learn when somebody tried to use my laptop. Is this straightforward to enable with PAM or the like?

Comment: do you run SSH? that could be a lot of emails for every failed SSH attempt...

Comment: I do run SSH, though I have my notebook at home (failed attempts would be very interesting) and in the institute which is behind a firewall. I would like to get those emails as well.

Comment: You could do something with `pam_exec.so` (see `man pam_exec`). Unfortunately I don't know pam well enough to make a full answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

`logwatch` will send you a daily email with a list of failed logins, among many other interesting bits of information gleaned from the system logs.